# Spring security Custom login page not redirecting

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I am using jsf servlet and created custom login page, used form with action j_spring_security_check ,method  POST , used j_username and j_password.
Problem i have when I click to Login button it's not redirecting to page but in Chrome network column it shows post method j_spring_security_check with 302 status code, am I using spring security proper way?

**Login.jsf page:**

```
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST" >
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <p:inputText type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="username"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <p:password type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" class="form-control input_pass" value="" placeholder="password" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn login_btn"  >Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Web Security config:**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successForwardUrl("/WelcomePage.jsf").failureForwardUrl("/addPicture.jsf").permitAll()

                .successForwardUrl("/WelcomePage.jsf")
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();

    }
```

Image from chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem, changed  action in form from j_spring_security_check to #{request.contextPath}/login and everything worked.